# postgresql create table in schema from another table in a different schema

Tags: postgresql

postgresql db. two schemas `1. base_layers 2. how`  each have their own unique login names (not superusers)

I am very simply trying to create a table in the base_layers schema from a table in the how schema from the base_layers connection sql window

I run this

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA base_layers TO how;

create table base_layers.man as
select * from how.hl_boundary
```

and it gives me this error

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation hl_boundary

********** Error **********

ERROR: permission denied for relation hl_boundary
SQL state: 42501
```

however when I run the same query through the postgres SQL connection window it correctly creates this table in the base_layers schema...

what do I need to do for the base_layers connection SQL window is able to create a table from a another schema

**how schema**

```
-- Schema: how

-- DROP SCHEMA how;

CREATE SCHEMA how
  AUTHORIZATION how;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA how TO how;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA how TO public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA how TO base_layers;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA how
    GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES
    TO base_layers;
```

**base_layers schema**

```
-- Schema: base_layers

-- DROP SCHEMA base_layers;

CREATE SCHEMA base_layers
  AUTHORIZATION base_layers;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA base_layers TO base_layers;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA base_layers TO public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA base_layers TO how;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA base_layers
    GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES
    TO public;
```

Comment: Did you run `ALTER DEFAULT` before or after these tables were created? That command does not change privileges on existing tables. Also, it only applies to tables created by the current user (unless you specify `FOR [role]`)

Comment: @Nicarus I ran the alter default after the tables were created

Comment: Then you need to run a separate `GRANT` command on the existing tables as the `ALTER DEFAULT` does not impact existing tables.

Comment: this worked for me, grant select on all tables in schema how to base_layers;

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant select privileges on that table to the user, like so:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE hl_boundary TO [user];
```

Replace `[user]` with the user you are running this command under.

Comment: nope still the same error. and I would want total access between both of these two schemas

Comment: Which **user** and **schema** are you running this under?

Comment: user: base_layers schema: base_layers

Comment: Then `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA base_layers TO how;` does not help you at all. You need `base_layers` to have access to your `how` schema. Did you `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA how TO base_layers;`?

Comment: yes and it gives me WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "how" .....

Comment: Does `base_layers` have `GRANT` privileges on the schema?